# In Google Docs Forms, how to change the multiple choice answer "other" to something else?

Tags: forms, google-docs, survey

I am trying to create a survey in Google forms and would like to create a multiple choice question with one of the answers being "Not acceptable (please comment)". I would like to allow the person to add some text after selecting this multiple choice answer.

When creating this multiple choice question in Google forms, it appears to have an option of "other" with a textbox but it does not allow me to change the default text "other" to something else. Does anyone know if it is possible to change the default text "other"? Or is there any other way I can do this? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK you can't change the default text of the last option in a Multiple Choice.

A workaround would be to keep the option that reads *Not acceptable (please comment)*

Then you would add a second question right after this (free text) that says:

*If you marked "Not acceptable", please comment on why:* (or something like that)

PS - the "other" option in this case is a single line text input field, **not** a larger box that displays text with a scroll bar for longer answers. A comment box that is not a multi-row input field would prevent users from seeing their longer answers easily, so the workaround might actually be the preferred solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll give it a try and see if works out. Hopefully google adds a feature like this soon, it would help a lot when creating multiple choice questions like these.